# MySQL inserta en un campo integer como "0" al poner "null"

Tags: mysql

necesito insertar "`null`" en un campo integer y al dar la orden me lo guarda como `0`. Alguien me puede explicar qué ocurre?

```
INSERT INTO tabla (id, campo) VALUES (1, null)
```

He probado con y sin comillas, con `undefined` y vacío y nada. Siempre me sale `0`.
Un saludo.

Comment: por que `UNDEFINED` no es un dato de tipo numérico, y tu deseas guadar esa cadena de texto o ese valor en una columna que solo espera enteros

Comment: Revisa la estructura de la tabla, quizá contenga un  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0   pégalo aquí y será más fácil ayudar

Comment: No veo forma de que pueda pasar lo que dices haciendo la inserción directamente. Para salir de dudas muestra el resultado de un `SHOW CREATE TABLE tabla`. Aunque el campo estuviera definido como `NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`, la consulta arrojaría el error: *`Column 'campo' cannot be null`*

Comment: [Te pueden votar negativamente porque no sabemos lo suficiente sobre tu base de datos.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2880/)

Comment: En realidad la tabla la creé con myphpadmin y cuando meto los datos desde la propia web me pone null. Además he marcado la casilla que lo permite...Soy bastante novata. Las tablas las creo desde la aplicación y los datos ya los meto con código...qué necesitáis?